# Having no luck getting started with Google API

Tags: google-api-python-client

I want to create an application which takes an existing set of mailing list messages and inserts them into a Google Group. Once I get to that point, I don't think the actual technical issues will be challenging, but for the life of me I can't seem to get authorized and execute one of the Google API sample scripts (the groupsettings.py script). I created a group and a project on the developers' console, enabled the relevant API, generated an OAuth client id and secret, downloaded the JSON for that, and ran the script:

```
python2.7 groupsettings.py --groupId=old-cr-archive@googlegroups.com --whoCanPostMessage=NONE_CAN_POST
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "groupsettings.py", line 169, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "groupsettings.py", line 166, in main
    access_settings(service=service, groupId=options.groupId, settings=settings)
  File "groupsettings.py", line 77, in access_settings
    g = group.get(groupUniqueId=groupId).execute()
  File "/Users/skip/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/skip/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 729, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/old-cr-archive%40googlegroups.com?alt=json returned "Backend Error">
```

The only explanation I found was "backend error". How do I figure out what that error really means? I haven't modified the groupsettings.py sample script. Is there a different simple script available somewhere which can help me debug my authentication problems?

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal error. I tried the same using Google [Groups Settings API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/groupssettings/v1/groupsSettings.groups.get) which should be working. It returns HTTP 500 Internal Server Error as well as your script. So apparently *something is rotten in the state of Denmark*. Hopefully it is temporary.